# Notify external service when a Contact record is changed

Tags: rest-api, webhooks

I have a connected app and I would like to create a something like a webhook to track all the "Contact" changes. Sales force has something like that?
There is this webhook in HubSpot where all the connected users that logged to my app has theirs updated sent to the URL I defined: https://legacydocs.hubspot.com/docs/methods/webhooks/webhooks-overview

I would like something similar for SalesForce: Everyone they logged in my Connected App and update a Contact, I receive this info in a URL I define.
For HubSpot I can configure this webhook direct from My Connected App. I believe that its not possible to do that in salesforce, so I was thinking in configure this webhook via API.

Comment: not sure about webhook .   but you can setup integration to make an api callout to your url   on every change of contact.  you can use flow or trigger to detect change in contact then make an api callout based on your critieria.

Comment: ^^^ aka "Salesforce webhook"

Comment: @gauravsharma Hello. is there an example on hoe to create a this flow or a trigger via  REST API?

Comment: basically you need to check your conditions in apex trigger or flow.  based on your condition you can make http callout using some async process like future method.  you can google search callout to external system from apex trigger or flow.   here is one such article  from a blog   https://salesforcehandle.com/http-callout-from-triggers-and-show-the-response/#:~:text=The%20only%20way%20that%20you,a%20response%20from%20the%20callout.

Comment: example using flow to make callout  :  https://www.infallibletechie.com/2020/04/how-to-do-callout-from-flow-in.html .  from flow  you can do tis wthout code also   with new httpcallout.  please refer to this article if this new feature works for you  https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.flow_http_callout.htm&language=en_US&type=5